# How to update monitor.getItem() in React Drag and Drop

Tags: reactjs, react-dnd

I was looking through the simple sortable example that React DnD gives in their [documentation](https://github.com/react-dnd/react-dnd/blob/master/packages/documentation/examples/04%20Sortable/Simple/Card.tsx) and they did a

`monitor.getItem().index = hoverIndex`

on Line 81.
However when I tried to do the same on my project this error occurred:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'index' of object '#<Object>' at Object.drop`

And without changing the `monitor.getItem()` my array goes crazy updating on hover.

Is there another way to update the monitor object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out,
on the
`beginDrag(props)`
I was returning props instead of returning a new object containing
`{index: props.index}`

Now it works like a charm!